# Android/Kotlin: unresolved reference: timber

Tags: android, kotlin, timber-android

I'm trying to write a kotlin library for Android and can't include timber. I always get the following error:

```
Error:error: unresolved reference: timber
```

I have this in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My source file is very simple at the moment:

```
package net.mbonnin.test

import timber.log.Timber

class Main() {

    fun main() {
        Timber.d("hello world")
    }
}
```

It fails on the import statement.

I'm using Android studio 3 canary 4 and kotlin 1.1.2-4.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Or is timber not usable in kotlin ?

Comment: Mmmmkay, Timber seems to be Android-only. I was under the impression that it could be used without android but I must have been wrong...

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue here.. Also you shouldn't compile the Gradle plugin like that. What is the rest of your gradle script?

Comment: Yes, I find it strange too. If there's an unmet dependency on Android.log, I would expect the error message to say so instead of just `unresolved reference`

Comment: have you refresh the gradle project to update your dependencies?

Comment: You have two `dependencies` sections. Perhaps the first one overrides the second one? Then Timber would never be included, and that would explain why you can't reference it in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
```

You're not applying any android plugin and thus don't know how to handle `@aar` artifacts. But these are the default artifacts when using Android libraries. Sometimes you might find `@jar` artifacts with the dependency as well, but not that often any more. And Timber is

> A logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility on top of Android's normal Log class.

You could teach Gradle to understand `@aar` files, but then you'd run into issues with the Android dependencies when using Timber.

So basically you have to make you module an Android Kotlin library instead.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```